# Browser does not Cache S3 objects using GeneratePresignedUrlRequest

Tags: caching, amazon-s3

I am developing an app where we store all files and images in S3. I am also trying to improve performance by using cache controls. Below is the sample code that i am using to add response-cache-control to the generated urls using GeneratePresignedUrlRequest

```
            System.out.println("Getting an object from  S3 \n");
            String bucketName = getParentBucketName(storeType);

            java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
            long msec = expiration.getTime();
            msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour.
            expiration.setTime(msec);

            String contentType = "application/octet-stream";

            switch (storeType){
            case presentation : contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation"; break;
            case pdf : contentType = "application/pdf"; break;
            case image : 
            case thumbnail:
                contentType = "image/png";break;
            default:
                contentType = "application/octet-stream";
            }


            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, key);
            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); // Default.
            ResponseHeaderOverrides responseHeaders = new ResponseHeaderOverrides();
            responseHeaders.setContentType(contentType);
            responseHeaders.setCacheControl("max-age=31536000");
            responseHeaders.setExpires(expiration.toString());
//            

            generatePresignedUrlRequest.setResponseHeaders(responseHeaders);



           return s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toString();
```

However, this does not work. The browser keeps requesting the file at the generated url again and again. For your information, the code above is executed each time i need to generate a url for a particular object in S3. I used chrome developer tools to see whether the Cache-Control exists in the response returned by S3. It is indeed there. I do not know why it is not working. Is there any thing that i am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Ameer

Answer (score 2):

The cached response can only be used by the browser when the request URL is exactly the same, including the query string... so if you are regenerating the signed URL each time, the browser would correctly consider that to be a different object, since the query string is different.

Comment: It depends heavily on your motivation for using signed URLs instead of making the content public.  Most of *my* applications with signed URLs involve content that it is very unlikely for a user to download more than once.  One option might be CloudFront signed cookies: you link the user to CloudFront, which will, based on the authorization granted by the cookie, internally sign a request to fetch the object from S3 with each request (if there's not a copy in the CF edge cache), but the browser's link would not have a query string, depending instead on the cookie for authentication.